# Postgres JSONB Type and TypeDef not working in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-3

I am using Spring Boot version 3 and cannot figure out how to make jsonb type column work with my JPA entity.

In the picture below it shows my case. I try to add @TypeDef but spring  "Cannot resolve symbol 'TypeDef'" and org.hibernate.annotations.Type Cannot resolve method 'type'.

I also tried to create a new @Data pojo object to be the type of the column but also i get an error.
I know this works in spring boot 2, but i don't know what to do in version 3.

Thanks

```
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import java.util.Map;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table (name = "parameters")
@TypeDef (name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Parameter {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "character", columnDefinition ="jsonb")
    private Map<String, Object> character;
```

[image]

Comment: You should insert your code as a code block, not an image, please. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I am not able to help you with your question as it is. Could you please add an [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?